# mysql query update a cell with variable Where criteria datetime field matches another variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried many syntaxes to update a cell in my database, but none of them worked. The following is my scenario.

My database has 3 fields of types Time(datetime), Flow(float) & Cumulative(float)

First I am getting the last two rows of data into variables and then wants to update/substitute the last row of Cumulative field where the criteria is with datetime field.

I suspect the problem is with datetime field (and (or) or) the quotes.

Here is the code.

```
$sql = "select * from Inflow_table ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 2";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$LastTime = $row[Time];

$Cumulativeupdate = 35.56; //Here a formula replaces the static value

mysqli_query("UPDATE  `Inflow_table` SET  `Cumulative` =  '.$Cumulativeupdate.' WHERE  `Time` =  '.$LastTime.' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

The rest of the code is working but it is not updating the Cumulative field. Please help me!

Comment: Does your table have an unique identifier such as an ID field auto increment primary key?

Comment: no, I dont have any ID fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to run mysqli_query which is not a built in function, change:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE  `Inflow_table` SET  `Cumulative` =  '.$Cumulativeupdate.' WHERE     `Time` =  '.$LastTime.' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `Inflow_table` SET  `Cumulative` =  '".$Cumulativeupdate."' WHERE  `Time` =  '".$LastTime."' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

and also remember to look out for SQL Injection vulnerabilities associated with mysql_* functions. Try to use:

mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

or

PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

change query to

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE  `Inflow_table` SET  `Cumulative` =  "'.$Cumulativeupdate.'" WHERE  `Time` =  "'.$LastTime.'" LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
```